# what's problem? how to use winappdriver in python. calculator automation

Tags: winappdriver

I don't know what the hell's wrong.
Why doesn't it work?

this is error message

and when I used to "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App" same problem too

### ======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (**main**.SimpleCalculatorTests)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\자동화\WinAppDriver-master\Samples\Python\calculatortest.py", line 29, in setUpClass
self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 257, in **init**
super().**init**(
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in **init**
self.start_session(capabilities)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\appium\webdriver\webdriver.py", line 346, in start_session
response = self.execute(RemoteCommand.NEW_SESSION, w3c_caps)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Bad capabilities. Specify either app or appTopLevelWindow to create a session

```
import unittest
from appium import webdriver

class SimpleCalculatorTests(unittest.TestCase):

@classmethod

def setUpClass(self):
    #set up appium
    desired_caps = {}
    desired_caps["app"] = "Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_11.2210.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe"
    self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4723',
        desired_capabilities= desired_caps)

@classmethod
def tearDownClass(self):
    self.driver.quit()

def getresults(self):
    displaytext = self.driver.find_element_by_accessibility_id("CalculatorResults").text
    displaytext = displaytext.strip("Display is " )
    displaytext = displaytext.rstrip(' ')
    displaytext = displaytext.lstrip(' ')
    return displaytext


def test_initialize(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("지우기").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("7").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"7")
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("지우기").click()

def test_addition(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("1").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("양의 값").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("7").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"8")

def test_combination(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("7").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("곱").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("9").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("양의 값").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("1").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("나누기").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("8").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"8")

def test_division(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("8").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("8").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("나누기").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("1").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("1").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"8")

def test_multiplication(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("9").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("곱").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("9").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"81") 

def test_subtraction(self):
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("9").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("음의 값").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("1").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_name("일치").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.getresults(),"8")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(SimpleCalculatorTests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

[image]

[image]